# Blacklist the vegetarianism tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism) seems awfully redundant to me. It's the site name. I think it's safe to assume that questions are *about* some subset of vegetarianism without tagging it as such.

[veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) *is* useful though, as that's a specific subset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's blacklisted now. Sorry about that - another side-effect of tweaking the subdomain choice ("vegetarianism" vs "vegetarian") during site configuration.

[veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) is still alive and well.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree completely.

[Tag & filter for all Subsets & Superset? Need Vegetarian & Lacto-Veg tag to differential & filter away from questions that are Vegan or Ovo-Lacto Veg?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/tag-filter-for-all-subsets-superset-need-vegetarian-lacto-veg-tag-to-diff)

Since, there is huge influx of "subset" participants from certain groups such as vegans, it biases the content (and answers) in that direction.

Why not allow people to pose questions towards the superset "vegetarian / ism" such that the responses do not go towards a specific subset or more towards the superset?

Also, why not understand what kind of subsets exist (as I have explained in my post/ response, and allow people to also direct them towards the subsets that are not "vegan".

Ref:  https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/1125/861

> Now, coming to the American/ Western worlds terminology use,

- Vegan - Plant only
- Lacto-Veg - Plant + Dairy (+maybe Honey) = Pure Vegetarian in India
- Ovo-Lacto-Veg - + Egg to the above = Eggetarian in India, maybe vegetarian in China (as lot of dishes that Chines call veg contain eggs - We have to caution against those too)
- Pescatarian - Veg + Fish - No meat (not sure how they are about eggs, mostly yes)
- The Pesco-veg - Mentioned in Riker's answer is a new one to me, if at all such exists. Every day you learn something new.
- Flexitarian - They well, define as and how and when what they wish to have and be :)

Comment: Vegetarianism tag has been blacklisted because it is the default theme of the site. This doesn't mean you can't ask questions on this topic. Tags are created by users that have this privilege and can be done if it is asked here, on meta, for an existing question. We do not create tags that doesn't have a purpose in advance, but only when it is needed. Some tags already exist like [tag:ovo_lacto] or [tag:pescetarianism]. You can see the full list [here](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tags).