# How do I search for questions without the vegan and veganism tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, search

There are a lot of questions with the tag [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) or [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) but if a user is only a vegetarian (and since the tag is now [blacklisted](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/38)), how can (s)he search for vegetarian-only questions?

I.e., how to view only a smaller subset set of questions with neither [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) nor [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) tags?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [`-[veganism]`](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bveganism%5D), however the [combo negation](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bveganism%5D%20-%5Bvegan%5D) doesn't seem to be working or maybe I'm not doing it right. Maybe we could do away with [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) altogether because it seems redundant.

Also, this only works if vegan users don't forget to use the [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) tag.

> [image]

Comment: I couldn't get combo negation to work either. It doesn't seem possible to exclude multiple tags in a search.

Answer (score 1):

The [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) tag [was synonomized](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/85/1236) with [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) a couple weeks after you asked this question, so now you can just search for `-[veganism]` to exclude all vegan content.

Another approach would have been to modify your [tag preferences](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/) so that both tags are ignored and you enable the option to hide questions for your ignored tags.