# Tag suffixes for subsets of vegetarianism

Tags: discussion, tags

In the spirit of tag cleanup, we should decide on a convention for tagging various diets.

Currently we use the following suffix's

***ism**

- [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism)
- [fruitarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruitarianism)
- [pescetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pescetarianism)

***-diet**

- [vegetarian-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarian-diet)

***food**

- [rawfood](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rawfood)

**No suffix**

- [raw](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw)
- [ovo-lacto](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovo-lacto)
- [plant-based](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant-based)

It seems to me that the *ism suffix is the most widely applicable, as it can encoumpas diet, ethics, and more. Suitably, [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) and [vegan-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan-diet) have both been made synonyms of [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism).  [vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism) [has been blacklisted](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/blacklist-the-vegetarianism-tag) however, which I suspect has put [vegetarian-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarian-diet) and [ovo-lacto](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovo-lacto) into usage.

I think we should:

1. Standardize around the *ism convention for all sub diets.
2. Blacklist [vegetarian-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarian-diet) and [ovo-lacto](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovo-lacto) under the same logic as [vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism).
3. Encourage combining *isms with other general tags such as [diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet), and [ethics](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) rather than create more unique tags like [plant-based](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant-based)

Comment: Why blacklist ovo-lacto? And I'd synonymize [vegetarian-diet] with [diet] (not exact, but probably good enough. the latter is a superset)

Comment: @Riker My thought was that vegetarianism is generally synonymous with ovo-lacto vegetarianism.

Comment: Hm, I see what you mean. I don't blacklisting it would be a good idea, but I'd be in favor of that if it becomes a problem.

Comment: @nloewen - The largest oldest Veg population on the planet will disagree with that hugely - Your viewpoint & knowledge is limited and biased towards the western/ American experience.

Comment: @Riker - Is this SE site going to be biased against ancient Veg viewpoints?

Comment: @AlexS not necessarily.  However, ancient history doesn't really matter as much as current definitions IMO.  I think that it's definitely not going to be as popular of a topic as modern veg\*nism, but that's okay, and there's not really anything we can do to enforce that. ('that' being 'ancient veg\*nism being the main focus of the site'). Honestly, 90% of people on this site aren't going to really care about ancient history I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the last year I've consolidated a lot of these. Now we have mainly *-ism*:

- [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism)
- [lacto-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-vegetarianism)
- [lacto-ovo-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-ovo-vegetarianism)
- [fruitarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruitarianism)
- [pescetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pescetarianism)

There are still a few *-diet* tags though for cases where no *-ism* word exists.

- [omnivorous-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omnivorous-diet)
- [therapeutic-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/therapeutic-diet)
- [rawfood-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rawfood-diet)