# Can we have a [lacto-veg] tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/1125/861 - Based on this classification of Veggie types (and maybe more types), would it not warrant equal privileges and filtering & tagging capabilities to all Subsets & the Superset to be accessible?

If "vegans" and "lacto-ovo" classes have the benefit of tagging their questions & posts, as well as the ability to filter/ search as per those tags, why not have tags for other classes as well? i.e. Laco-veg and maybe posts that are meant for "superset" Vegetarian so as to specify that this does not go a "vegan" or sub class way when a question is intended towards Superset and not subset.

Give us the **Lacto-veg** tag / category for our subset.

Why should we not able to "direct" a question towards a Superset "Vegetarian" when we can direct it towards a subset "vegan".

Comment: As a technical aside, it is not possible to create a tag absent of a question to apply it to.

Comment: @Erica - I'll post a Question & Answer and you give it that tag? I do not wish for that effort to go waste with it disappearing without the said tag/ classification

Answer (score 2):

The reason broader tags (e.g. [vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism)) are generally blacklisted is that *every question* on Vegetarianism could reasonably be tagged with it.

If there are sufficient questions about lacto-vegetarianism or yogic-vegetarianism, they absolutely should get a tag! However, those questions need to exist first; we don't create a tag and then wait for interested users to come create content. The purpose is to organize content, not preemptively establish areas of interest. (If you've got a bunch of [lacto-ovo](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-ovo) questions, we would love to have them.)

Based on your other concerns, I will also point out that tags definitely do not exist to indicate a preference for a certain type of question. The reason a specialized subset [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) tag was created was because we have gotten numerous [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan)-related questions.

Comment: Its not about "special tags" but representing & giving "tags" to "major" classes. I've done content management for Global corps & "primary/ major classes/ types" are defined at get go, then secondary & tertiary come into play as usage comes about. To not welcome the largest class of "veg" populace is favoritism & bias towards "Western" privilege online. Online veg narrative is always driven by the west. No worries, will leave this SE in peace & not share any of the 1000s years of herbal veg knowledge I would've shared. Good luck. Once again, felt very unwelcome.

Comment: But we can't tag what isn't here yet. I honestly don't understand how that would work.

Comment: Did Veg SE start with zero tags? unlikely. You chose initial tags "you thought" were relevant. Right?

Comment: When the beta was opened, there were indeed zero tags. Tags got created as questions were asked. If it was based on MY personal belief or diet preferences, we'd have a pescatarian tag ;) but since I have not asked a pescatarian question yet, we do not.

Comment: It exists - https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pescetarianism - Not saying one belief is more important than another,  whats key is set of "known main" classes/ sub types of Veg-ism exist, why not just allow for those to be explained in a Wiki/ Post and have tags for them. 

Because of how "web" works population w "more internet access" will Bias content & narrative in their direction. Hence, despite more Lacto-veg on earth, the "western world" with "privileged" Net access overshadow with "vegan narrative", Rich/ Powerful getting Richer/Powerful, Poor getting poorer.

Comment: Its the opposite of Net Neutrality where the majority that have the powers get to eliminate the minority narrative. In gardening terms, until we encourage a seed, the saplings will never show, cause the weeds have already taken over.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a focus on the tag rather than the content. There absolutely are more vegetarians than there are vegans, but your experiences with other veg communities are coloring your perceptions. StackExchange just doesn't work the same way -- as questions are asked, tags are generated.

Comment: I will post Q&A and will you give it a tag? I do not wish for that collected knowledge & effort to get lost untagged and unclassified. Yes, I thought my perceptions were colored, but rightly so - The larger populace seems to dictate the online content narrative. Part of the reason by a Kim Kardashian article gets more attention than anything else, no matter how serious, knowledgeable or important - Digital Majority wins no matter the lack of Merit.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I think vegetarian (lacto-ovo) yah is useful to signal that OP wants to focus on that rather than vegan answers. While there aren’t so many vegans they tend to be more active/vocal in the community and they can dominate conversations on particular issues. So it is important to know where specific interests of lacto-ovo or vegan groups can be discussed (without being too exclusionary if possible).

Comment: @Erica I’m also now practicing “pescetarianism” (and have ensured that it is welcome since the inception of the site). However, I’ve yet to ask a question specific to this lifestyle so I have not used this tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough reputation, anyone can create a tag. The bar is not particularly high (although may have been lower while the site was in Beta). Participate in asking and answering questions for a while and you will get various additional privileges (until you can essentially moderate the site). This includes creating new tags on your questions or edit them on others. *You do not need to request that a specific tag be added*. However, there are community guidelines as to what topics are appropriate for a tag such as wide enough interest or not being to vaguely defined.

For example, I created the [ovo-lacto] tag while the site was in Beta. Note that this tag is no longer used and has been updated to [lacto-ovo-vegetarian] as per another Meta post.

Answer (score 1):

We do have these tags now. They were created [last year](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/301/1236).

- [lacto-ovo-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-ovo-vegetarianism)
- [lacto-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-vegetarianism)

Comment: Thank you for the update.