# Let's rename [ovo-lacto] to [lacto-ovo-vegetarianism]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, user-interface

**Let's rename [ovo-lacto] to [lacto-ovo-vegetarianism].**

I noticed that in the tagging prompt to ask a question, typing in `vegetar` displayed the option for [lacto-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-vegetarianism) but not [ovo-lacto](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovo-lacto). It seems *much* more likely that somebody is going to start by typing "vegetarian" rather than "ovo". Sure, this could be remedied by modifying one of the tag excerpts to mention ovo-lacto, but why bother when we could just get the name right to start with?

[image: Typing vegetar at the tag prompt gives four options: vegetarian-diet, is-it-vegetarian, traveling, lacto-vegetarianism]

Oh, and I suggest changing the order because Google Trends indicates that "lacto-ovo" is much more common usage, especially in North America.

[image]

Yes, the tag is longer but I think that's okay. StackOverflow also ended up moving toward longer tag names over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were only four questions with this tag so I just retagged them.

Now we have [lacto-ovo-vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lacto-ovo-vegetarianism).

Answer (score 0):

For what it’s worth, I think I created this issue by creating the tag. I felt that “vegetarian” was redundant since it’s the name of the site (too broad) but this raises a good point. I’m okay with the change. I’m not American, which may explain why it was alphabetical. Again, it doesn’t matter as anyone searching of the original tag would find these renamed.